# How to do a partial post in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to asp.net mvc.

I want to create a site that allow the visitor to do a partial post such as allowing visitors to press a `like` button to vote a comment.

How to do this in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement this using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), the browser will send a post "behind the scenes" so to say, without redirecting the user. The server will return data in [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json).

On the server: Create a new Controller `CommentsController` and add a Action `Like`:

```
[Authorize] /*optional*/
public JsonResult Like(int id)
{
    //validate that the id paramater
    //Insert/Update the database
    return Json(new {result = true});
}
```

In your view, simply use the [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods:

```
function likeComment(id) {
    $.post('<%=Url.Action("Like", "Comments")%>/' + id, function(data){
        //Execute on response from server
        if(data.result) {
            alert('Comment liked');
        } else {
            alert('Comment not liked');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Substitute <%=Url.Action("Like", "Comments")%>/ with @Url.Action("Like", "Comments")/ if you are using the Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC is **not** limited to use **only one** form in the page like Web Form. While [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) solution is preferred to your scenario, you can also use normal [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) as below;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { controller = "Comments", action = "Like" })) {
    <button type="submit">Like</button>
}
```

Comment: @Recycle Bin: can you explain about partial update? But I'm sure that code only POST without any data which means this.Request.Form has no value.

Comment: @Soe: I have not tried your code above. Let us assume that I use your code. If the visitor press the `Like` button, does he/she cause the whole page to be posted back to the server and then the server send back to him/her the new update page? If yes, your solution is not what I want.

Comment: @Recycle Bin: Yes, it does postback. That's why I mention that Ajax solution is preferred to your scenario. :) But I post my answer because some people doesn't know that there can be many forms. Real world usages is Stackoverflow's search feature is using that technique.

Comment: @Soe: Do you mean in a single html page we can have more than one `Html.BeginForm()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  It has two forms, search and post-form (ask question). I think the master page/layout has search form and the questions#ask view has post-form (ask question). You can check using firebug or other development tools. :)